# How do I compute a determinant with JavaScript, with input as a LaTeX input format?

Tags: javascript, math, matrix, latex

How do I compute a matrix determinant, with LaTeX input format, such as:

```
1 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\ 
-2 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1
```

Should one use `JSON.parse(...)` to convert this format into an array, and then use a JavaScript function to compute its determinant?

Note: this question originally comes from [Fastest way to compute a determinant from a LaTeX matrix input](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2650941/109021) but it's impossible to post an answer with code snippet there, thus an answer here, that can be interesting on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an online JavaScript solution, using [the math.js library](http://mathjs.org/).

Run it below, and paste this into it, it will work!

```
1 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\ 
-2 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 & 1
```

```js
$('#a').on('input', function() {
    try {
        var s = $('#a').val();
        var t = '[[' + s.replace(/&/g, ',').replace(/\\\\/g, '],[') + ']]';
        var A = JSON.parse(t);
        $('#b').text(t);
        $('#c').text(math.det(A));
        $('#d').text(math.inv(A));
        $('#e').text(math.multiply(math.det(A),math.inv(A)));
    } catch (err) {
        $('#b').text("Incorrect input");
        $('#c').text("");
        $('#d').text("");
        $('#e').text("");
    }
});
```

```css
#a { width: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.20.2/math.min.js"></script>

<input id="a" placeholder="Paste LaTeX matrix"></input>
<br><br>Array format: <div id="b"></div>
Determinant: <div id="c"></div>
Inverse: <div id="d"></div>
Det * Inverse: <div id="e"></div>
```